# When booting into Elementary OS...NOT from a hard restart...no wired internet connection

Tags: ethernet

OK.

Setup.
Asus H87I-Plus Micro ITX motherboard
16 GB RAM
1 TB SSD hard drive (standard...not the little one)
Dual boot with Windows 10 home

Problem.

If I do a complete hard boot (pushing the power button on my computer to turn it on from completely being off) and I choose either the Elementary OS or Windows 10 in GRUB...no problem.   Can boot into either OS, no problem...can get onto the internet with a wired internet connection in both environments.

Everything is peachy.

But.

If I'm in Elementary OS and I select RESTART, or even SHUT DOWN...or if I'm in the Windows 10 environment and I select restart and I try to enter Elementary OS using GRUB from any restart option...

The Elementary OS environment isn't allowing me to go onto the internet.    It's saying connected...but using Chrome, Firefox and Opera...none of the browsers are showing me connected to the internet.

This is a problem specific to Elementary OS.    A restart doesn't fix the problem.

What fixes the problem is I hold down my power button on my computer...the system does a hard shut down...I push the power button again...choose Elementary OS in GRUB...and my wired connection once again allows my browsers to go online.   It's not just the browsers either.   My email client (Blue Mail) also won't receive emails unless I hard boot my elementary OS environment.

Is there a setting in the BIOS that has an impact on Elementary OS but doesn't have the same impact on Windows 10?   I've never been able to connect to the internet on my Windows environment since I built my PC 8 years ago.   Elementary OS has been the first cog.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The descripted issue might be caused by a lot of things.
I would like to suggest to start with setting the nic as managed by NM.

See [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/change-netplan-renderer-from-networkd-to-networkmanager/) for some instructions.

Comment: This is so weird.   It's no longer an issue.    No fricken idea what I've done other than upgrade the Nvidia graphic driver.   That can't possibly have been the reason I'm sure.